# Magento Sever Configuration for large DB

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, configuration, server

I was developed the Social network related project in Magento,and then in my application having 3 lakhs(customer) record,when i was upload the files to our dummy demo server,with minimum record it was worked fine, but after import the 3lakhs record it is not loading, it throw max execution time exceeded.

After i increase the max-execution time,it throw memory exhausted error.

I was search in google to find the solution,most of the solution they mentioned only in my server configuration related.

So can you please suggest how much configuration server is needed to handle this kind of large DataBase.

I am looking quick response from your end.

Comment: in fact _What is the Best Magento Server Setup?_ is not a real answer, looks like bla-bla-sonassi-bla-bla...

Answer (score 0):

Magento comes with a default .htaccess file in the root directory that includes this configuration directive.

```
  php_value memory_limit 64M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

You can simply change this value from 64MB to 96M or 128MB depending on your needs. This value should be kept to the minimum necessary to run your application.

Hard Coded 32M memory_limit.

If you are running this off a shared server, your memory_limit may be locked down to 32M so you're forced to fairly share resources with others on the server. Magento doesn't run well on shared servers that have not been optimized for Magento, btw.

Your web server may not be set up to use memory_limit out of .htaccess and thus requires you to use a php.ini file to set memory. See the php.ini.sample file that Magento installs in its root folder for what the php.ini file contents need to be.

Otherwise, check with your hosting service provider and ask them to bump the limit to 512M.